# Vue @click.native not working?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have navigation component like this:

```
<template>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Website Builder</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" @click.native="currentView='create'">Create</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" @click.native="currentView='how'">How</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" @click.native="currentView='about'">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" @click.native="currentView='youtube'">Videos</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
</template>
```

and my js:

```
Vue.component('navigation', Navigation)
Vue.component('create', Create)
Vue.component('how', How)
Vue.component('about', About)
Vue.component('youtube', Youtube)

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        currentView: 'create'
    }
```

and html:

```
<div id="app">
    <navigation></navigation>
    <keep-alive>
        <transition name="slide-fade" mode="out-in">
            <component :is="currentView"></component>
        </transition>
    </keep-alive>
</div>
```

However when I click on navigation, it doesn't change therefore I am assuming it's not working properly. if I put navigation away from component and stick it in div id=app it works fine, why is this happening?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. The `.native` modifier is not necessary on native elements - it can only be used on component elements. Remove it.
2. It seems you want to change data in the root component. Your current code changes data  in the navigation component.

Two ways to do this:

### 1) The clean way:

In the navigation component, we emit an event with the new value to the parent:

```
<a href="#" @click="$emit('current-view', 'youtube')">
```

in the parent (here, the root) component, we receive the event and set the value:

```
<navigation @current-view="currentView = $event"></navigation>
```

### 2) The hacky way:

```
<a href="#" @click="$root.currentView='youtube'">
```

Comment: Tested the clean way. Working. But is it just me or it doesn't feel right? Still feels somehow "hacky", like something we should avoid.

Comment: Found this article talking about communicating between components... May clear some thoughts https://flaviocopes.com/vue-components-communication/