# Vuejs 2.x How to remove active class when click on non ul link

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to remove active class from all Li has same class but could not get right code to do that in vuejs 2.x.

my code example is here : 
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ravanand1988/eywraw8t/258939/)

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    active_el:0
  },
  methods:{
    activate:function(el){
     if(el === 0) {
        // remove active class from all Ul>>Li
        }else {
        this.active_el = el;
        }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
ul > li:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
}
.active {
  color:red;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<a href="#" @click.native="activate(0)" :class="{ active : active_el == 0 }">link 0</a>
 <ul>
    <li @click="activate(1)" :class="{ active : active_el == 1 }">Link 1</li>
    <li @click="activate(2)" :class="{ active : active_el == 2 }">Link 2</li>
    <li @click="activate(3)" :class="{ active : active_el == 3 }">Link 3</li>
  </ul>
  
  <ul>
    <li @click="activate(4)" :class="{ active : active_el == 4 }">Link 1</li>
    <li @click="activate(5)" :class="{ active : active_el == 5 }">Link 2</li>
    <li @click="activate(6)" :class="{ active : active_el == 6 }">Link 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

active class should be removed from all li under Ul tag when **link0** is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a console.log to the activate function you will see that the @click.native in the a tag does not work. I removed the '.native' (+ the if else) and the snipped works for me.

More infos about the .native:
[Vue @click.native not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47094620/vue-click-native-not-working)

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    active_el:0
  },
  methods:{
    activate:function(el){
        console.log(el);
     this.active_el = el;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
ul > li:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
}
.active {
  color:red;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<a href="#" @click="activate(0)" :class="{ active : active_el == 0 }">link 0</a>
 <ul>
    <li @click="activate(1)" :class="{ active : active_el == 1 }">Link 1</li>
    <li @click="activate(2)" :class="{ active : active_el == 2 }">Link 2</li>
    <li @click="activate(3)" :class="{ active : active_el == 3 }">Link 3</li>
  </ul>
  
  <ul>
    <li @click="activate(4)" :class="{ active : active_el == 4 }">Link 1</li>
    <li @click="activate(5)" :class="{ active : active_el == 5 }">Link 2</li>
    <li @click="activate(6)" :class="{ active : active_el == 6 }">Link 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    active_el:0
  },
  methods:{
    activate:function(el){

     this.active_el = el;

        /*if(el === 0) {
        // remove active class from all Ul>>Li
        this.active_el = 0;
        }else {
        this.active_el = el;
        }*/
    }
  }
});
```

```css
ul > li:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
}
.active {
  color:red;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<p href="#" @click="activate(0)" :class="{ active : active_el == 1 }">link 0</p>
<br/> <br/>
 <ul>
    <li @click="activate(1)" :class="{ active : active_el == 1 }">Link 1</li>
    <li @click="activate(2)" :class="{ active : active_el == 2 }">Link 2</li>
    <li @click="activate(3)" :class="{ active : active_el == 3 }">Link 3</li>
  </ul>
  <br/> <br/>
  <ul>
    <li @click="activate(4)" :class="{ active : active_el == 4 }">Link 1</li>
    <li @click="activate(5)" :class="{ active : active_el == 5 }">Link 2</li>
    <li @click="activate(6)" :class="{ active : active_el == 6 }">Link 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I think you just forgot to input the condition when `el === 0`

Comment: You don't even need the `if` and `else` for this example, as the first link will emit a 0 as function parameter.

Comment: I tried this, it's not working unfortunately. you can have a look in shared jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `.native` tag since the `<a>` is a native element by itself. Also, you can simplify your `activate` method:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    active_el:0
  },
  methods:{
    activate:function(el){
        this.active_el = el;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
ul > li:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
}
.active {
  color:red;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<a href="#" @click="activate(0)" :class="{ active : active_el == 0 }">link 0 {{ active_el }}</a>
 <ul>
    <li @click="activate(1)" :class="{ active : active_el == 1 }">Link 1</li>
    <li @click="activate(2)" :class="{ active : active_el == 2 }">Link 2</li>
    <li @click="activate(3)" :class="{ active : active_el == 3 }">Link 3</li>
  </ul>
  
  <ul>
    <li @click="activate(4)" :class="{ active : active_el == 4 }">Link 1</li>
    <li @click="activate(5)" :class="{ active : active_el == 5 }">Link 2</li>
    <li @click="activate(6)" :class="{ active : active_el == 6 }">Link 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```